# Google Analytics service Intent crashes on Android Oreo

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-8.0-oreo

I have upgraded my app to support SDK 26 and now Google Analytics causes crashes when running on Android Oreo:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver
>   com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH
>   cmp=com.example.android/com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService
>   }: app is in background uid UidRecord{3f302e5 u0a107 RCVR idle procs:1
>   seq(0,0,0)}
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3259)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start
>   service Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH
>   cmp=com.example.android/com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService
>   }: app is in background uid UidRecord{3f302e5 u0a107 RCVR idle procs:1
>   seq(0,0,0)}
>          at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1505)
>          at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1461)
>          at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
>          at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
>          at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaot.onReceive(Unknown Source:68)
>          at com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver.onReceive(Unknown
>   Source:11)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3252)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

This is my relevant Manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
    android:resource="@xml/analytics"/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

<!-- Optionally, register AnalyticsReceiver and AnalyticsService to support background
     dispatching on non-Google Play devices -->
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"/>

<!-- Optionally, register CampaignTrackingReceiver and CampaignTrackingService to enable
     installation campaign reporting -->
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

Having hundreds of Oreo devices crashing due to this in past 24 hours. Seems to be affecting only on install. I am going to try and add android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" to the 2 analytics services and see. Will report.

I Will be happy to provide more info if needed. Thanks

Comment: Can't find anything online, looks like you're the first to encounter this issue. Can't reproduce it myself because of a lack of Android 8 devices, though this should be answered soon.

Comment: We're getting a similar error from Oreo devices for the CampaignTrackingService:

Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.overdrive.mobile.android.mediaconsole/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService (has extras) }

Comment: I have raised the issue with Google Analytics: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65788222 . Anyone having this issue can add their concern as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend upgrading to play-services version 11.4.0. Add this in your Gradle file:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.0
```

From the [Play Services Revision 11.4.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#september_2017_-_version_1140), analytics section:

- Added a new class `AnalyticsJobService`. This class provides compatibility support for Android O and is used by Analytics to upload data. No action is necessary to use this class, it’s added automatically as part of the Analytics package.
- Deprecated the `getContext()` method of the `AnalyticsService` class.
- Deprecated the `CampaignTrackingService` class.

and also you have to get permission.
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"

See below 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/AnalyticsJobService

Comment: Why didn't Google release this PRIOR to Oreo is beyond my understanding?

Comment: using version 11.6.0 , issue still happening

Comment: using version 15.0.2 and still have this issues :'(

Comment: using version 16.0.6 and still have this issue.

Comment: using version 17.0.0 and still have this issue

Comment: Using version 17.0.0 and still have this issue.

Answer (score 4):

because `CampaignTrackingService` is now Deprecated

just remove this line from your manifest

```
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"
         android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: but it recommended in official manual - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns

Comment: @SergeyTokarev : Where is in the documentation says recommended? i have seen many times but didn't found. Document only says 1. Remove the Google Analytics receiver from your AndroidManifest.xml file. - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-implement