# Google Analytics will crash on Android Oreo

Tags: android, google-analytics

my google service version is **com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1**，my google analytics version is 16.0.1.

error infomation is :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to create application com.tinkerpatch.sdk.loader.TinkerPatchReflectApplication:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH cmp=appid/com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{2a069ca u0a15 TRNB bg:+1h53m19s560ms idle procs:2 seq(0,0,0)}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262082/google-analytics-service-intent-crashes-on-android-oreo