# How do I handle this crash?

Tags: android

I use the version is 11.4.2
this is the log:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:Unable to start receiver
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD
>   cmp=/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService (has
>   extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{81230bc u0a190 TRNB
>   bg:+2m52s798ms idle change:uncached procs:1 seq(51,51,51)}

I checked the firebase-analytics source code and found that there is a paragraph code in the AppMeasurementReceiver directly `context.startService()` as follows:

```
public static ComponentName startWakefulService(Context context, Intent intent) {
        synchronized (sActiveWakeLocks) {
            int id = mNextId;
            mNextId++;
            if (mNextId <= 0) {
                mNextId = 1;
            }

            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_WAKE_LOCK_ID, id);
            ComponentName comp = context.startService(intent);
            if (comp == null) {
                return null;
            }

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                    "wake:" + comp.flattenToShortString());
            wl.setReferenceCounted(false);
            wl.acquire(60 * 1000);
            sActiveWakeLocks.put(id, wl);
            return comp;
        }
    }
```

But I went to check the latest version of firebase and found that this code has not been modified, so how is it caused? How to deal with it?

Comment: If you haven't checked !! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46262082/google-analytics-service-intent-crashes-on-android-oreo..

Comment: Thanks, my current project does not use com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.0. After adding this library, will the Google service not trigger the AppMeasurementService but trigger the AnalyticsJobService?